# Limits of a two variable function

Tags: calculus

So I have to find limits of a function with rules:

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 1 &x^2+y^2\leq 1,\\ \dfrac{x+y}{1+x^2} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
 at points $A(1,1)$ and $B(1,0)$. What I did is: limit at A is $(1+1)/(1+1^2)$ since the function is well defined at $A$ and limit at $B$ is $1$. Is this true? Thanks

Comment: For $B$ take $x=1$ and small $y=\epsilon >0$ what is the limit as $\epsilon\to0^+$?

Comment: The limit in $A$ is correct to me.

Comment: @kingW3: seems it should tend to 1.

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x,0)$ ?

Comment: @B.S. How did you get that?

Comment: @kingW3: Now I see what I was wrong.... I was blind and did not notice to the boundary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is fine.

$B$ is not: that point is at the boundary of the closed disk where the function is everywhere equal to $1$, so *at* $B$ the function has value $1$. However, the limit there does not exist! If you approach $B$ from the negative-$x$ direction (from the left) you stay within the disk, so the limit along that path is $1$:
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(1-h,0) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} 1 = 1; $$
however, if you approach $B$ from the *positive*-$x$ direction (from the right) the function is defined using the second formula and you get
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(1+h,0) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{1 + h + 0}{1 + (1+h)^2} = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{1 + h}{2 + 2h + h^2} = \frac 1 2. $$

Comment: Yes, that's what I do in my answer